# How to call testLDAPConnection method from Keycloak admin cli v6.0.1?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

We've just upgraded our Keycloak server from version 3 to version 6.0.1.
We have some custom script that we use together with the Keycloak admin cli, for testing LDAP user storage connectivity.

However it seems that the method `testLDAPConnection` is not working anymore in version 6.0.1 as it returns **HTTP 405 Method not allowed**.

It appears that the `testLDAPConnection` method was changed and doesn't accept a GET request but only a POST request. 
The [Admin CLI documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#storage-provider-operations) states that the `testLDAPConnection` method can still be used in the old way:

```
    $ kcadm.sh get testLDAPConnection -q action=testConnection -q bindCredential=secret -q bindDn=uid=admin,ou=system -q connectionUrl=ldap://localhost:10389 -q useTruststoreSpi=ldapsOnly
```

This will fail with a HTTP 405.

I've tried using the **create** verb as follows:

`$ kcadm.sh create testLDAPConnection -s action=testConnection -s bindCredential=secret -s bindDn=uid=admin,ou=system -s connectionUrl=ldap://localhost:10389 -s useTruststoreSpi=ldapsOnly`

I expected this action to return a HTTP 204 code but instead it results in an error message saying **"LDAP test error"**, cause **"KC-SERVICES0054: Unknown action: null"**.

It seems that the method is reachable but the parameters are not sent properly.
I noticed in the source code that only the `testLDAPConnection` method has FormParam parameters types, so my guess is that the admin cli doesn't know how to set those.

I've searched this issue in the Keycloak issues backlog but I couldn't find anything.

Anybody had this problem or has any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I have exactly the same error. A bug has been opened on Keycloak issue tracker (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-10967?jql=text%20~%20testLDAPConnection) but no response yet...

Comment: It's confirmed to be an issue in kcadmin as well as documentation. Should be fixed in version 9.0.1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a problem also in Keycloak v7 so I decided to create a script to work around this issue.

Basically I request a token and then I use the token to call the **testLDAPConnection** API.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

KC_USERNAME=$1
KC_PASSWORD=$2
KC_SERVER=$3
KC_CLIENT_ID=$4
KC_CLIENT_SECRET=$5
REALM_NAME_IMPORT=$6
KC_CONTEXT=auth
CURL_OPTS="-k --noproxy $KC_SERVER"

# Request Token
KC_RESPONSE=$( \
   curl $CURL_OPTS -X POST \
        -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
        -d "username=$KC_USERNAME" \
        -d "password=$KC_PASSWORD" \
        -d 'grant_type=password' \
        -d "client_id=$KC_CLIENT_ID" \
        -d "client_secret=$KC_CLIENT_SECRET" \
        "http://$KC_SERVER/$KC_CONTEXT/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
    | jq .
)

# Split token
KC_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(echo $KC_RESPONSE| jq -r .access_token)

# Verify if there is an acces token 
if [ $KC_ACCESS_TOKEN  ]; then

    echo "Token acquired successfully"
    exec 3>&1 

    # iterate through the hostnames csv file
    while IFS="," read -r cluster hostname bindcredential; do

        # Test if the given pair of LDAP host name and password is valid 
        KC_RESPONSE_LDAP_TEST=$( \
            curl -w "%{http_code}" -o >(cat>&3) $CURL_OPTS \
                -X POST \
                -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
                -H "Authorization: Bearer $KC_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
                -d "action=testAuthentication&bindCredential=$bindcredential&bindDn=cn=root,o=test,c=ro&connectionTimeout=&connectionUrl=ldap://$hostname:389/&realm=$REALM_NAME_IMPORT&useTruststoreSpi=ldapsOnly" \
                "http://$KC_SERVER/$KC_CONTEXT/admin/realms/$REALM_NAME_IMPORT/testLDAPConnection"  \
    | jq .
)
        # if the response is valid(204) we continue do whatever we want to
        if [ "$KC_RESPONSE_LDAP_TEST" == "204" ]; then
            echo "Keycloak testAuthentication for configuration "$hostname" was successful."
         else
            echo "ERROR: Couldn't connect with "$hostname" or authentication failed (incorrect password)"
        fi

    done < ldaps.csv

else
    echo "UNAUTHORIZED. No access token available"
fi
```

and I run the script from the command line:

```
./testLDAPConnection.sh <username> <password> <keycloak_server> <client_id> <client_secret> <realm_to_operate>
```